# Put Windows 7 to Sleep using VBA

Tags: windows, vba, sleep-mode

I have some VBA code which takes hours to run.
After completion of the code, I want the windows 7 (64 Bit Professional) to go to SLEEP.

What VBA code can I use at the end to achieve this?

Comment: I dare claim that code that takes several *hours* to run is likely to be highly optimizable. I'd be curious to see that code and what can be done to make it run [perhaps much, much] faster. If you're as curious as I am and you *can* share this code, feel free to put it up for review on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not aware of a way to do this natively in vba. Usually for these sort of things I'll search the internet for a way to do it in the command prompt, then have my vba run a command line script.

Sure enough, here is an explanation of how you can shut down / sleep via command line.

https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu

And you'll find many examples online of running command line scripts from vba which you can use to execute these commands. At it's most basic, something like this:

```
shell "notepad.exe"
```